# Magento 2 Top links

Tags: customer-account, magento2.2.2

How to change the actions of top links in Magento 2

```
My Account --> customer/account to My Account --> customer/dashboard
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by create a plugin of class `Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link`.

First create a **plugin** for `Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link` of function `getHref()`. Then on **`afterGetHref`** changes the **dir** of backup.

### Define plugin in di.xml

Define plugin at a **`app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/di.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link">
        <plugin name="change_toplink_url" type="{VendorName}\{Modulename}\Plugin\AccountLinkPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

### Plugin Class:

```
<?php
namespace {VendorName}\{Modulename}\Plugin;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface; 
class AccountLinkPlugin
{  
 /**
 * @var UrlInterface
 */
protected $urlBuilder;

public function __construct(
    UrlInterface $urlBuilder
)
{
    $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
}
    public function afterGetHref(
        \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link $subject,
         $result
    )
    {
        return $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('customer/account/dashboard');

    }

}
```

You need to do di compile and cache flush in to active this plugin.

Comment: Please elaborate i am new in magento

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Xudot\ReferralCredit\Plugin\AccountLinkPlugin::afterGetHref() must be of the type array, string given

Comment: Have done  di complie?

Comment: I just remove {array  $result} from class and it works

Comment: ooh, my mistake.Yes it should be string not array